# NSUserDefaults deleting keys when close the app

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I need to delete keys when application will close. So what should I do?

Comment: If you need to delete these keys when the app closes, why are you putting them in the defaults system in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete keys from `NSUserDefaults` using the following code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

in your `ApplicationDelegate` method following which state are you meaning by "close the app":

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the documentation

```
- removeObjectForKey:
```

*Removes the value of the specified default key in the standard application domain.*